# MSW - Mock Service Worker - "Operation has been aborted"

Tags: javascript, service-worker, msw

I ran into this error when using the library [msw](https://github.com/mswjs/msw).

```
[MSW] Failed to register the Service Worker:
Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with script ('http://localhost/mockServiceWorker.js'): Operation has been aborted
```

[image]

An important thing is, **if I use another browser or a different Chrome profile, it'll work just fine**.

I tried clearing cache but that doesn't help. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`, set "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost" to **Enabled**.

---

I resolved the issue with this search:[image]